# How to load images in a Cocoa Touch framework?

Tags: ios, swift, bundle, cocoa-touch

I have created the Cocoa Touch base app and have tried to load images programmatically. I have placed my images in the bundle resources. Through storyboards the images are loaded, however, but is does not work programmatically. The images won't show up.

Comment: You need to get the framework bundle correctly.

Comment: If I select via file Inspector if the images loaded in storyboard. but same like if I do via programmatically.
imageView.image = UIImage(named:"image.jpg")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are creating framework for using in another projects, So in your framework you want to access your frameWork bundle get the frameWork bundle by below code.

```
func getBundle() -> Bundle? {
    var bundle: Bundle?
    if let urlString = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YOUR_FRAMEWORK_BUNDLE_NAME", ofType: "framework", inDirectory: "Frameworks") {
        bundle = (Bundle(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: urlString)))
    }
        return bundle
}


let bundel = getBundle()

imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg", in: bundel, compatibleWith: nil)
```

Comment: whether that inDirectory: fields must?

Comment: Yes, While integrating your framework to any Project it will come under that directory. Try it and let me know

Comment: You are creating FrameWork or Application?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147333/discussion-between-vara-and-bala).

Comment: Thanks, Its Working fine. @Bala